# how to use multiple hidden fields with the same name

Tags: laravel-5

hi i'm trying to get the rate for a product i tried this :

```
<div class="pro-rate">
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="1" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation" id="1" value="1"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="2" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation" id="2" value="2"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="3" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation" id="3" value="3"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="4" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation" id="4" value="4"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="5" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation" id="5" value="5"></span>
```

but it keeps give me only the value of 5 nothing else , how can i get each value as i want not only the last one ?

and here is the full form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{action('onlyController@postIndex')}}" method="POST">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    @foreach($product as $pro)

                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$pro->id}}" />

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">الاسم </label>

                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="inputName" placeholder="الاسم " required>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">الاميل </label>

                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="الاميل" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">نص التعليق </label>

                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="comment" maxlength="1000" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="reviews">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">التقييم </label>
                                    <span>ردئ</span>
                                    <div class="pro-rate">
                                        <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="1" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation[]" id="1" value="1"></span>
                                        <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="2" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation[]" id="2" value="2"></span>
                                        <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="3" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation[]" id="3" value="3"></span>
                                        <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="4" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation[]" id="4" value="4"></span>
                                        <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="5" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation[]" id="5" value="5"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <span>ممتاز</span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn ">ارسال </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    @endforeach
                    </form>
```

how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

use 'evaluation[]'

but evaluation will be an array on server

```
  <div class="pro-rate">
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="1" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation[]" id="1" value="1"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="2" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation[]" id="2" value="2"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="3" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation[]" id="3" value="3"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="4" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation[]" id="4" value="4"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rate="5" ><input type="hidden" name="evaluation[]" id="5" value="5"></span>
```

$_POST['evaluation'] is going to be an array

```
 $evaluation = $_POST['evaluation'];
 foreach($evaluation as $val){
    //do something with the values here
 }
```

ok, well all seems to be working for me

```
<?php
 if($_POST)
        print_r($_POST['email']);
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
 Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br> 
 E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>

 hidden <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value='hjdfkhds'  ><br>
 hidden: <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value='iufd'><br>
 hidden: <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value='78642di'><br>
 hidden <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value='uidynsx' ><br>
 hidden <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value='qsqaaa'><br>

 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

after I clicked submit. This is what I got

[image]

[image]

Comment: in each input or just onetime ?

Comment: each input. So when you catch it $evaluation = $_POST['evaluation']. You will need to cycle through each one to get the values

Comment: it's not right it gives me that error : preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array and it's inserted as an array not the value

Comment: one moment will post you how the form should look like

Comment: hope it helps. Can I ask, are you using an MVC?

Comment: i don't think it works like that but i will edit the post to show u the whole form

Comment: please do not use  <input type="hidden" name="email[ id ]" value='uidynsx' >. just empty brackets and it should be ok. post up your code. I'll have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107476/discussion-between-mohamed-elbiheiry-and-h-bensiali).